# how long does it take to get an rss feed after content has been published?

Tags: performance, rss, feed

I recently installed an RSS feed on our company forum.  I did some tests and it appears that if I subscribe to a feed it takes at least 45 minutes before I receive the rss for published material.  Is this usual?  Is there a faster way to receive updates?

Comment: It depends on how often your feed reader is set to retrieve feeds, and how often they are published... There isn't really a question to be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the time but it always depend in the client to accept it or use a fixed value

http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltttlgtSubelementOfLtchannelgt

Comment: That element only provides guidance, different aggregators may provide different behaviour, so you can't rely on it.